# Selenium - Log in with URL failed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium am having trouble authenticating to a website. I was provided a link that automatically authenticates me and redirects me to a homepage of a the site. When I try running this code below I am just redirected to the login page and it says authentication failed(Changed the link for obvious reasons). I use the same link on my browser and it logs me in. Am I missing an option that I have to specify somewhere?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ec2-user/test/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://examplelink.com/#/login?token=aewoijfadsklnfwjeojwfqoj234ihg')
```

Comment: This is an issue with the website itself, and not selenium. Can you manually navigate to the URL with the token in it? You usually can't authenticate with just a token unless it's through API. Through UI, the website will also look for browser cookies and other indicators of authentication -- token alone is not enough.

Comment: Yes, if I just use that URL with the token inside it will log me in.

Comment: This is probably because your regular / manual browser has cookies from your previous login. When starting a selenium browser, it is essentially wiped clean, almost like an incognito mode instance. If the code does not work in selenium, there's not much you can do except actually log in with selenium.

Comment: can you put real site and temporary token? or minimum the site name?

Comment: Ah ok got it thanks, I am not allowed to share a token as only a few companies have access to this specific site.